# Displaying image with id on certain part of page but not elsewhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, ajax

I want to make the image with id EleId to display on a certain part of page but not display for elsewhere. What is a way for doing this? Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleView(switchView) {
  if (switchView == "list") {
    document.getElementById(EleId).style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (switchView == "thumbs") {
    document.getElementById(EleId).style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

Using this code above causes the image with EleId to hide and show everywhere on the page.

Perhaps using DIV tags for area I want to be affected by this code? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: This will never work, you are missing a brace after each getElementById call and you are using really wrong the getElementById. Please first read this:https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.getElementById and them try again.

Comment: Well, first of all that mean that you have multiple control with the same id on your page, which is not recommended. If you want to hide a specific image, it got to be contexted to is parent or something else. Can you show us your HTML ?

Comment: JavaScript is the only tag that should apply to this question. Also the code is not syntactically correct - you are missing parentheses and curly braces.

Comment: ianaya89, were just typos in code. You get the idea of what I want to do. Fixed anyways!

Comment: All typos are fixed. You can not even look at the code and understand "Trying to make image with these Ids hide and show on certain part of page only. Causes them to hide and show everywhere on page since they are used multiple times using same Id. "

Answer (score 0):

Got a few problems here.  First, your function accepts a variable called 'switchImgTag', but then it appears to be checking the value of the variable 'switchView', which I don't see defined elsewhere in your code snippet, so I assume this is a mistake.  Second, getElementById does exactly what you'd think - gets elements by their IDs.  EleID.style.display = "none" is not an ID, so that won't work.
  Lastly, I can't be sure without seeing your HTML, but it seems that you're using the same ID for multiple images, which is a really bad idea, so I would correct that FIRST.

Comment: Yes there were typos i corrected. Trying to make image with these Ids hide and show on certain part of page only. Causes them to hide and show everywhere on page since they are used multiple times using same Id.

Comment: well, if you're unwilling to correct the duplicate ID problem, why don't you try using CSS classes?

Answer (score 0):

Commenters are correct. There are formatting errors, but that was probably just a mistake since you said it was hiding all the elements on the page (i.e. the code was sorta working).

If you're going to have multiple elements on the page, you can't use IDs. You need to use classes. I thought I might add a solution that doesn't even require javascript at all just maybe to inspire a way of doing it. It requires certain things of the markup (this one requires the `elem` class to be a next sibling of the original "img" elements). This could be adjusted, but you'll need to make sure the .img boxes have a `tabIndex="0"` so they can receive focus.

### CSS-only solution

```css
.img { 
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  background: gray;
  border: .5em solid #eee;
  margin: 1em;
}

.elem { 
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  background: lime;
  display: none;
}

.img:focus + .elem { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<h1>Click the gray box to show the elem div</h1>
<div class="img" tabIndex="0"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>

<div class="img" tabIndex="0"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>

<div class="img" tabIndex="0"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>

<div class="img" tabIndex="0"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
```